# how to loop over cell range in a fast way or any other alternative for following code

Tags: excel, vba

First of all i don't have any knowledge in macros and have compiled the following code using google.
 It is executing but I have to loop over a large range multiple times which is slow. How can I make it fast
 the code is

```
Public Sub getsum()

For a_counter = 1 To 41194

 skunow = Sheets(2).Range("A" & a_counter).Value
 sumofthissku = 0
        For b_counter = 1 To 99944
        anothersku = Sheets(1).Range("A" & b_counter).Value
                  If anothersku = skunow Then
                  qty = Sheets(1).Range("H" & b_counter).Value

                                If IsNumeric(qty) Then
                                sumofthissku = sumofthissku + qty
                                End If

                  End If
        Next b_counter
       Sheets(2).Range("B" & a_counter).Value = sumofthissku

      Next a_counter

      End Sub
```

Explain--> I have two sheets sheet1 and sheet2
sheet 1 contains sku with their quantity. But the sku is repeated multiple times.
sheet 2 contains all sku only one time and i have to sum the quantity from sheet 1 and put it in sheet 2.

values 99944 and 41194 i am hardcoding by number of rows in both sheets.

Comment: What not use a sumproduct formula instead?

Comment: Don't hardcode row numbers, you can use Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).end(xlup).row to get the last row, this is dynamic so much better than hard coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to go via the VBA way. Let's say your data looks like this

[image]

Use the Sumproduct Formula in the first cell and use the `Autofill` feature.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8=E3)*($B$1:$B$8))
```

If you **still** want a VBA solution then you can store the ranges in an array and then perform the calculations in memory and then dump the data back.

Comment: Out of curiosity Siddharth, why a sumproduct and not a sumif?